# How can I solve this ajax request problem?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-8

I'm rather new to Laravel and ajax.

I am trying to use this ajax request to update the information in the database from the data input from a form, I'm using datatables. I can create the entry fine and when I click to edit it brings up the modal which is populated fine but when I change some info and click update it doesn't succeed as I never get the console.log and I get a 500 internal server error.

This is my ajax request inside my Blade file.

```
// UPDATE AJAX REQUEST
                $("#edit_vehicle_form").submit(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    const fd = new FormData(this);
                    $("#edit_vehicle_btn").text('Updating...');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '{{ route('update') }}',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: fd,
                        cache: false,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(res) {

                            console.log(res)


                        $("#edit_vehicle_btn").text('Update Vehicle');
                        $("#edit_vehicle_form")[0].reset();
                        $("#editVehicleModal").modal('hide');
                        fetchAllVehicles();
                        }

                    });
                });
```

This is the request from the controller.

```
// UPDATE VEHICLE
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $fileName = '';
        $veh = Vehicle::find($request->id);
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $fileName = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->storeAs('public/images', $fileName);
            if ($veh->image) {
                Vehicle::destroy('public/images/' . $veh->image);
            }
        } else {
            $fileName = $request->image;
        }
        $vehData = [
            'make' => $request->make,
            'model_name' => $request->model_name,
            'version' => $request->version,
            'powertrain' => $request->powertrain,
            'trans' => $request->trans,
            'fuel' => $request->make,
            'model_year' => $request->model_year
        ];
        dd($veh);
        $veh->update($vehData);
        return response()->json(
            ['status' => 200,]

        );
    }
```

You can see that the information is received by the browser inside the payload.

```
_token: TvpFRMBCUzXSJOksan8l3hLwgLyN3C3bttk3qliB
id: 1
image: 1652901564.png
make: BMW
model_name: 7 Series
version: M5
trans: Automatic
fuel: Petrol
powertrain: 540ti--e-xDrive
model_year: 2022
image: (binary)
```

and that the data is processed into Json for the database entry.

```
array:7 [
  "make" => "BMW"
  "model_name" => "7 Series"
  "version" => "M5"
  "powertrain" => "540ti--e-xDrive"
  "trans" => "Automatic"
  "fuel" => "BMW"
  "model_year" => "2022"
]
```

I think I have tracked it down to the ajax in my blade file but after further research I have come to a standstill.

**ADDED**

```
#40 C:\\wamp-server\\www\\vehicle-db\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 C:\\wamp-server\\www\\vehicle-db\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(142): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#42 C:\\wamp-server\\www\\vehicle-db\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 C:\\wamp-server\\www\\vehicle-db\\public\\index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 C:\\wamp-server\\www\\vehicle-db\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\wamp-server\\\\...')
#45 {main}
"}
```

The last 4 lines from my lavarel log.

There is no new errors in my PHP log or my Apache log.

Comment: Your `_token` is not among the json going to your controller. Can't that be issue? because laravel wont allow that.

Comment: I wasn't sure if all the information needed to be re-parsed. I will look at how to pull the token in and reply afterwards. Thank you.

Comment: If you get a 500 error in PHP, then you should have a stack trace in your web server logs. Could you find out what that is, and put it in your question?